Ubuntu 24.04.1 MPI webcam on Dell XPS 13 (9315) still not recognized
I still cannot fix the problem of MPI camera not being recognized on my Dell XPS13 (9315) despite the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1.
I tried without success the fixes proposed in this thread and also elsewhere.
When I run the command "v4l2-ctl --list-devices" the camera is listed, but neither launching cheese nor guvcview from the terminal with sudo fixes the issue.
I added my username to the video group as suggested (https://itsfoss.com/no-camera-found-ubuntu/), but no results.
The laptop is in dual boot, and under windows the camera works fine, but I cannot consider this as being the solution.
I am not fully confident I can properly apply by myself the patch proposed here, as I need some guidance: https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers
Did anyone test it?
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Guido

Can't give much help, since I prefer to stay on 22.04 just to avoid this problem. According to Dell, the problem is currently yet to be solved, see https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/it-it/000225004/precision-5480-mobile-workstation-webcam-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-24-04?lang=en

The webcam still does not work with Cheese or Guvcview but a couple of hours ago (november 26, 2024) it worked connecting to a Webex meeting through the browser (Chromium). I just tested it on gUM Test Page and it works: https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html
What is happening?

Update: at one point my camer has stopped working even with 22.04 (probably a kernel updated), so I've decided to jump into 24.04. After an half afternoon of swearing, I managed to get it back working, following various comments in the github issue 228 of the aforementioned repository. Pay attention, because there are two distinct Dell PPA, but you should be able to understand the correct one (the other one is very old and misses many recent LTS versions).
